# SQL Server: multiple TRUE/FALSE rows to one BIT row with a TRUE/FALSE condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck with a code in T-SQL. I tried to update a global result from multiple true/false rows with only one condition if any of all values from "values column" is true then the global value is true. The REF and REF_GLOBAL columns are the same.

Like this example :

*Here there is only one REF but I got something like REF1, REF2, REF3, etc...*

SOURCE_TABLE :

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|REF |VALUE_1|VALUE_2|VALUE_3|
+----+-------+-------+-------+      
|REF1| FALSE | TRUE  | FALSE |
|REF1| TRUE  | FALSE | FALSE |
|REF1| TRUE  | FALSE | FALSE |
|REF1| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
+----+-------+-------+-------+  

GLOBAL_TABLE :

+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|REF_GLOBAL |VALUE_1|VALUE_2|VALUE_3|
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|REF1_GLOBAL|   1   |   1   |   0   |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

When there is only one row it's easy :

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.VALUE_1 = (CASE WHEN T2.VALUE_1 = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    T1.VALUE_2 = (CASE WHEN T2.VALUE_2 = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    T1.VALUE_3 = (CASE WHEN T2.VALUE_3 = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM GLOBAL_TABLE T1, SOURCE_TABLE T2
WHERE T1.REF = T2.REF_GLOBAL
```

But I'm stuck when I want to do this from multiple value to one value considering that if a least one value is true then the global result is 1.

I'm sure this is something related to 'if statement' with an 'any' clause but even after reading multiple documentation and forum I can't find how to deal with that.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**over 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You are right, I need to quit this bad habit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not even using the global table, and instead just using conditional aggregation to generate a the output you want to see:

```
SELECT
    REF + '_GLOBAL' AS REF_GLOBAL,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE_1 = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALUE_1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE_2 = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALUE_2,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE_3 = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VALUE_3
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
GROUP BY
    REF
ORDER BY
    REF;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

This answer assumes that your logic is to report a 1 should a given value column have one or more `TRUE` values across a common group of reference records.

One motivation for not maintaining the global table is that its data is simply a derivation of the source table.  In theory, everytime the source table's data changes, the aggregates in the global table would become stale, and might have to be updated.

Comment: I use this method. You were right not using the global table is the best way to deal with my problem. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Tim Biegeleisen's answer: You can take advantage of the [`bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type handling values `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` as `1` and `0` respectively. As forpas pointed out, aggregation on a `bit` is not supported so an additional `cast` is needed.

```
select Ref + '_GLOBAL' as Ref_Global,
  Max( Cast( Cast( Value_1 as Bit ) as Int ) ) as Value_1,
  Max( Cast( Cast( Value_2 as Bit ) as Int ) ) as Value_2,
  Max( Cast( Cast( Value_3 as Bit ) as Int ) ) as Value_3
  from Source_Table
  group by Ref
```

Creating a *view* probably makes more sense than saving the value in a table unless you encounter specific performance issues.

Aside: For those preferring obfuscation one can employ the rules for [data type precendece](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and use `Max( Cast( Value_1 as Bit ) + 0 ) )` to conceal the intent. That's not recommended for maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `EXISTS` performs better in this case because it will return as soon as it finds 'TRUE':

```
UPDATE GLOBAL_TABLE 
SET
  VALUE_1 = CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE VALUE_1 = 'TRUE' AND REF_GLOBAL = REF + '_GLOBAL') THEN 'TRUE' 
    ELSE 'FALSE' 
  END,
  VALUE_2 = CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE VALUE_2 = 'TRUE' AND REF_GLOBAL = REF + '_GLOBAL') THEN 'TRUE' 
    ELSE 'FALSE' 
  END,
  VALUE_3 = CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE VALUE_3 = 'TRUE' AND REF_GLOBAL = REF + '_GLOBAL') THEN 'TRUE' 
    ELSE 'FALSE' 
  END  
WHERE REF_GLOBAL = 'REF1_GLOBAL';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac03b166497322c9faeb0d1e34955055).
Results:

```
> REF_GLOBAL  | VALUE_1 | VALUE_2 | VALUE_3
> :---------- | :------ | :------ | :------
> REF1_GLOBAL | True    | True    | False
```